# Discontinuous Almost-Everywhere/ Unbounded in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ be defined as usual, with the equivalence relation : $f \approx g$ if and only if $f(x) = g(x)$ almost everywhere.

Is there a class in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ such that every element is discontinuous almost everywhere ? Is there another class such that the every element is discontinuous everywhere ?

Thank you very much :)

EDIT : Now I know about the existence of a set $A$ that is dense, has measure greater than zero and its dense complement also has measure greater than zero. It solves this problem.  (thanks to David Mitra)

EDIT 2 : Can you help me now with another question ? Is there a class in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that every element is unbounded in every non-empty open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: What is a representant?

Comment: A member that defines a partition in the equivalence relation

Comment: Shouldn't that be "a class in $L^1(\mathbb{R}) such that *every* element is discontinuous almost everywhere"?. It seems to me that in every class of $L^1$ there's a a.e. discontinuous representative, namely $f + \alpha\mathbf{1}_\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: yes it's that what i meant.

Comment: The characteristic function of a Cantor set seems a good candidate for the first question...

Comment: Isn't the characteristic function of a Cantor Set equivalent to the function identically zero ? (which is continuous) I mean, it differs from this last one in a set of measure zero, right ? Should we use Fat Cantor Set ?

Comment: One can construct a measurable set $A\subset[0,1]$ such that for any interval $I$, both $A\cap I$ and $A\cap I^c$ have positive measure. Try the characteristic function of this set.

Comment: @ David Mitra : Thank you so much ! Now i know that such thing exists, following the construction of Fat Cantor Set. This way we have two dense sets that are disjoint and have measure positive and it fits the purpose just like we want.

Comment: by the way, can you help me with the new question ? I cannot figure it out an example in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ of a class such that every element is unbounded in every open interval that is not empty in $\mathbb{R}$. Perhaps I can adapt the function that you suggested, but i cannot see how it stays in $L^{1}$... I hope I'm not annoying you :) Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, here is a solution to the first question and what i think solves the second one :)
Following David Mitra's cool suggestion : Let $A$ be a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that is dense and has measure greater than zero and its dense complement also has measure greater than zero. We can construct such $A$ applying the iterative process of Fat Cantor Set, also to the "every middle interval that is excluded on each step".
Then, defining $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^{2}}$ for each $x \in A$ and $f(x) = 0$, otherwise, we have that every equivalent function to $f$ in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, is discontinuous every where.
Regarding my second question, I THINK (not sure, though), that the following example works : Let $f(x)=x^{\frac{-1}{3}}$ and let $\mathbb{Q}=\lbrace q_{n} \rbrace$. Then define : $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}}f(x-q_{n})$. It's clear that is in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and it's unbounded in each open interval. Also, every other equivalent function is unbounded in each open interval, due to density of rationals.